# Can't read a config value in development.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this:

```
# config/setting1.yml
var1: 11
var2: 12

# config/initializers/setting1.rb
Rails.configuration.setting1 = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'setting1.yml'))[Rails.env]

# config/environments/development.rb
//Doing something with Rails.configuration.setting1
// Rails.configuration.setting1['var1']
```

For some reason, I get an error in `development.rb` which is  `undefined method setting1' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000010543f1b0> (NoMethodError)`

Why is that? Doesn't development.rb get loaded after `initializers/setting1.rb` has been loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializers are loaded after `config/environments/development.rb`. You can see more on Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html